# Can the chunks compressed by timescale db be deleted directly?

Tags: timescaledb

I want to delete some obsolete and compressed chunks. Do I need to decompress them before I delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently you need to decompress data before you can delete it. This [issue tracks](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/2857) the work to delete decompressed data directly.